# N-dimensional linear representation of symmetric group S(N)

Tags: symmetric-groups, gap, irreducible-representation

A beginner's question on the linear representations of the symmetric group $S(n)$: playing around with [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/), e.g.:

```
gap> CharacterDegrees(SymmetricGroup(n));
```

for various values of $n$, it appears that, no irreducible representation of dimension $n$ exists, except if $n = 5$. In fact, there are two 5-dimensional representations of $S(5)$. My questions:

1. Is it correct that $S(n)$ has no irreducible representation of dimension $n$, except if $n = 5$? If yes, what is special about $S(5)$ that is allows a 5-dimensional representation?
2. How do I construct the 5-dimensional representations of $S(5)$?

Thanks

Comment: I meant to say something else... what's "special about 5" -- I don't really know, but you should expect $S_n$ not to have low-dimensional representations because it wants to be simple and low-dimensional representations want to have kernels, and you should expect more exceptions to this heuristic for smaller $n$ (where e.g. $GL_m(F_2)$ is larger in cardinality than $S_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $S_5$ has 6 Sylow 5-subgroups, so it acts on them by conjugation. This gives an embedding $S_5 \hookrightarrow S_6$ which turns out not to be conjugate to the "standard embedding". There are two irreducible representations of $S_6$ given by the standard representation and its twist by the sign, and these turn out to restrict to irreducible representations of $S_5$.

You are right that no other symmetric group has this property -- if I understand the Wikipedia article right, this follows from the full classification of representations of the symmetric group in terms of Young diagrams, but there might be an easier proof I don't know.`